# What sizes of bricks (building scales) have carried the Lego brand name?

Tags: history

Apart from regular Lego and Duplo, what other sizes of brick have there been that have carried the Lego name? What is the compatibility between the different building scales?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The sizes are:

- Regular Lego bricks.
- **[Duplo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Duplo)**. Intended for younger children. Bigger than regular Lego bricks, but compatible with them. Some are branded "Duplo", whereas others carry the "Lego" brand. Still produced.
- **[Quatro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Quatro)**. Intended for younger children than Duplo. Bigger than Duplo, and compatible with Duplo. No longer produced.
- **[Primo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Baby)**. Intended for babies. Bigger than Quatro, and compatible with Duplo with special interface bricks.
- **[Modulex](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Modulex)**. Intended for architectural models and commercial signage. Early sets were branded Lego. Not compatible with regular Lego bricks. No longer produced.
- Samsonite **[Jumbo Bricks](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Jumbo_Bricks)**. Not compatible with regular Lego bricks. No longer produced.
- [Lego Soft Bricks](https://education.lego.com/en-us/products/lego-soft-brick-set/45003). Not compatible with regular Lego bricks.
- Lego Storage Bricks are brick-shaped boxes for storing Lego. Some of them can be stacked, so you can "build" with them. However, they're not compatible with other bricks.

There are also various "bricks" used as promotional material, such as the large fibreglass ones you see at the Legoland theme parks. You can't build with them, and they're obviously not compatible with regular Lego.

Although they *didn't* carry the Lego brand name, **[Olo and Minitalia](https://forum.brickset.com/discussion/16074/lego-minitalia-italy-and-lego-olo-japan)** were made by Lego for the Japanese and Italian markets. They're the same size as regular Lego, and compatible with it. They're no longer produced.

Answer (score 7):

Besides Classic and Duplo (2x as big in each dimension, hence the name) there are several more official dimensions of LEGO bricks:

1. Quatro: 2x as big as Duplo in each dimension, so 4x as big as LEGO Classic: [http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=48201#T=S&O={}](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=48201#T=S&O=%7B%7D)

[image: Quatro brick]

2. Modulex: Smaller brick width than Classic LEGO (5/8th), and with a 1:1 relation between height and width, whereas Classic LEGO has a 6:5 relation: [http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=Mx1111L#T=S&O={}](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=Mx1111L#T=S&O=%7B%7D)maller

[image: Modulex brick]

3. Jumbo: Fits in between Duplo and Quatro, 3x LEGO Classic in each dimension: [http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=x1446#T=S&O={}](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=x1446#T=S&O=%7B%7D)

[image: Jumbo brick]

4. Primo: 2x as big as Jumbo in each dimension, hence 6x Classic LEGO: [http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=31000#T=S&O={}](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=31000#T=S&O=%7B%7D)

[image: Primo brick]

There are still several more sizes, reported in [Dag Bricks' excellent spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qDhCdQKOn1GGxv6D0xu1CDW1Msv2aE0QxFG-AlZbOSo/edit#gid=0), but they are not similar to normal bricks in form and/or function, such as LEGO Gears, LEGO Soft Bricks and LEGO Tubs and cups.

Here is a comparison picture between some formats; from top to bottom: Modulex, regular, Duplo, Quatro and Soft Brick:

[image: Five bricks of different sizes, stacked]

---

Source used: http://www.dagsbricks.com/2013/09/lego-techniques-system-sizes-wrap-up.html

Comment: The bottom brick in your last photo looks like a Soft Brick, not Quatro

Comment: The image of the five stacked red bricks does note end with Quatro. It's Modulex, Lego, Duplo, Quatro and the bottom one is 6 times larger than standard Lego. You can easily tell since Quatro uses hollow studs just like Duplo. But I also measured pixels in the picture to make sure. Jumbo Bricks is not in the picture.
I found this page when searching for what Lego called the sizes 6x and 20x the standard brick. My search will go on... Thanks!
Pontus