# LEGO brick size between classic and duplo?

Tags: size

What is the LEGO brick called that is between Classic and Duplosize?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What sizes of bricks (building scales) have carried the Lego brand name?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/391/what-sizes-of-bricks-building-scales-have-carried-the-lego-brand-name)

Comment: There is no Lego brand brick scale between regular Lego and Duplo. [This post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6995/middle-size-lego-bricks) has some more information.

Comment: Are you sure they're LEGO brand bricks? They could be a copycat brand.

Comment: Hi Carol! Could you post a picture of this brick? Preferably a close-up shot with a regular LEGO brick as size reference.

Comment: I've merged the two questions linked by @MatthewJensen. Hopefully this creates a more complete source for this information.